# Adding an Array to ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: scala

I am trying to add an Array to `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` `(collectedData)` in Scala 2.11:

```
stream.foreachRDD { rdd => Collections.addAll(collectedData, rdd.collect()) }
```

I got the following compilation error:

```
[error]  found   : java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue[(String, String)]
[error]  required: java.util.Collection[_ >: java.io.Serializable]
[error] Note: (String, String) <: Any, but Java-defined trait Collection is invariant in type E.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]     stream.foreachRDD { rdd => Collections.addAll(allReceived, rdd.collect()) }
```

Can someone give me a hint as to what these errors mean?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your stream?

The error message tells you, that you have a collection for tuples of strings.
But you need a collection, where you can insert instances of Serializable.
This usually means that somewhere a type was inferred that you did not intend.

Did you explicitly declare the type of stream?
If not, try doing that and probably you will get a type error somewhere, where the real problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Arrays.asList with the splat syntax along with the ConcurrentLinkedQueues add all method:

`collectedData.addAll(Arrays.asList(rdd.collect():_*))`